# Laravel pessimistic locking locks entire table instead of a single row

Tags: laravel, pessimistic-locking, rowlocking

Laravel Version: **7.15**

PHP Version: **7.4.6**

Database Driver & Version: **MariaDB 10.4.11**

Below code is going to return array response for each invoices.
Once action method called for `id=1` it takes 20 sec to get committed.
When the same method called for `id=2` response waits until the first transaction is finished.
why row-level locking is not working.

```
protected function actions($id)
    {
      DB::beginTransaction();
      try {
          if($id==1)
            sleep(20);

          $invoice = Invoice::lockForUpdate()->find($id);
          $name = 'Approve';
          if ($invoice->approved) {
             $name = 'Disapprove';      
            }
         } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack(); 
         }
      DB::commit();

        return [
            'name' => $name,
            'id' => 'menu-approve',
            'data-status' => $invoice->approved
        ];
    }
```

---

It was previously working on Laravel **6.x**

A `lockForUpdate()` locks a specific row until it was committed successfully (`Select * from invoices where id=1 FOR UPDATE`). But `select * from invoices where id=2 FOR UPDATE` should not be wait until the first query get committed. Also without specifying a lock ( `Select * from invoices`) records are not drawn and it waits the first transaction to be committed. What could be the possible reason to lock entire table instead of a single row?

In **7.x** when you locked a single row, the entire record(table) gets locked!.

Comment: What is the DB and it's engine that you are using?

Comment: @VinayakSarawagi Laravel's database query builder class

Comment: Please run "SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>;" and let me know what is the value that you see for "ENGINE=".

Comment: InnoDB engine @Vinayak